# twitter python script generates error

Tags: python, twitter, bots, twitter-follow

Hy. So I installed python 2.7.9 and the twitter follow bot from github. I don't really know what I'm doing wrong but when I try to use a command I get an error. using this `from twitter_follow_bot import auto_follow_followers_for_user`results in this
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    from twitter_follow_bot import auto_follow
  File "twitter_follow_bot.py", line 21, in <module>
    from twitter import Twitter, OAuth, TwitterHTTPError
ImportError: cannot import name Twitter`
Any idea what I did wrong. I never use python before so if you could explain it to me step by step it would be great. Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

In `from twitter import Twitter, OAuth, TwitterHTTPError` "Twitter" does not exists in "twitter". Try to re-download or double check if that file is even within "twitter".

Comment: and how can I do That?

Comment: re-download - simply uninstall "twitter", or "twitter
_follow_bot" (which ever one you downloaded) or delete it then re install it just like you did the first time. To check the file use your file explorer and locate the file directory.